# How to clone/copy repo into another Azure DevOps project?

Tags: git, azure-devops

How to clone/copy repo into another Azure DevOps project? I've seen fork option however it then gives possiblity of merging it back, which I don't want, I would like to copy/clone existing repo into new project and preserve its history.

Comment: Hi @Yoda, as Shamrai Aleksander has shared, you can import source files from an existing repository into a new empty repository on Azure DevOps. If it is helpful to you, please mark his answer as the solution of this topic. It may help more people who have the similar questions when they are looking for an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a new repository and import data into it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops

Steps

1. Create a new empty repo in another project.
2. In your existing repo press Clone, Generate Git Credentials and remember URL and user data

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Use this information in the import repository wizard of the new repo.

[image]

Comment: Worked a treat for me - Azure Devops even sends you an email when the import is complete, handy if you have a huge repo to import.

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't get this to work until following your instructions which include creating/using credentials

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new repo is not necassary since import creates a new one automatically.